# Runing Nexus behind an SSL Reverse Proxy with Custom Context Path

Tags: nginx, nexus, nexus3

I'm trying to run nexus behind an SSL Reverse Proxy, where nexus is not working with custom context path.

I've also updated with Base URL Capabilities in nexus as https://dev

```
location / {    
    .....
    .....
    }
```

With **location /** the request works properly, however it does not work with **location /nexus**

Below is my nginx config for reference

```
  server {
    listen   *:443;
    server_name  dev;
  
    client_max_body_size 1G;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 2G;
  
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      dev-test.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  dev-test.key;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5s;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;  
  
    location /nexus {   
        proxy_pass http://server:8081/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the native context path of Nexus Repo to match the context path in the reverse proxy.

Edit $datadir/etc/nexus.properties and set:

```
nexus-context-path=/nexus
```

Or if running in a container, add this to the INSTALL4J_ADD_VM_PARAMS environment variable passed into the instance:

```
-Dnexus-context-path=/nexus
```